# Vue package css is missing

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, npm

I am using Laravel 6 and Vue js. However, I want to add social share buttons and I have installed [this](https://github.com/nicolasbeauvais/vue-social-sharing) vue js package to do this.

I have ran `npm install --save vue-social-sharing` and added the following to the `app.js` file:

```
import VueSocialSharing from 'vue-social-sharing'

Vue.use(VueSocialSharing);
```

The social share button is also showing up, but without any styling being applied. It looks like this (its yellow because all my `a` tags are styled so):

[image]

Can anybody tell me why the css of the package is missing...?
This is my vue js component:

```
<div class="col-xl-4 actions no-padding">
    <ShareNetwork
        network="twitter"
        url="https://news.vuejs.org/issues/180"
        title="Say hi to Vite! A brand new, extremely fast development setup for Vue."
        description="This week, I’d like to introduce you to 'Vite', which means 'Fast'. It’s a brand new development setup created by Evan You."
        quote="The hot reload is so fast it\'s near instant. - Evan You"
        hashtags="vuejs,vite,javascript"
        twitterUser="youyuxi"
    >
        <i class="fab fah fa-lg fa-twitter"></i>
        <span>Share on Twitter</span>
    </ShareNetwork>
</div>
```

Kind regards

Comment: The package doesn't include any (CSS) styling. However if you search through the repo you can find [an example](https://github.com/nicolasbeauvais/vue-social-sharing/blob/master/examples/App.vue) on how they created some basic styling

Comment: Ok.. strange. But where does `a.share-network-twitter { background-color: #1da1f2; }` this come from? It says `Inline.css`, means, it has to be in the package in my eyes.